# c#: regex how to differentiate between two variations of a string

Tags: c#, regex, string, dynamic, builder

This is tough to explain enough to ask the question, but i'll try:

I have two possibilities of user input:

S01E05 or 0105  (two different input strings)

which both translate to season 01, episode 05

but if they user inputs it backwards E05S01 or 0501, i need to be able to return the same result, Season 01 Episode 05

The control for this would be the user defining the format of the original filename with something like this:
"SssEee"  -- uppercase 'S' denoting that the following lowercase 's' belong to Season and uppercase 'E' denoting that the following lowercase 'e' belong to Episode. So if the user decides to define the format as EeeSss then my function should still return the same result since it knows which numbers belong to season or episode.

I don't have anything working quite yet to share, but what I was toying with is a loop that builds the regex pattern. The function, so far, accepts the user format and the file name:

```
public static int(string userFormat, string fileName)
{

}
```

the userFormat would be a string and look something like this:

> t.t.t.SssEee

or even

> t.SssEee

where t is for title, and the rest you know.

The file name might look like this:

> battlestar.galactica.S01E05.mkv

Ive got the function that extracts the title from the file name by using the userFormat to build the regex string

```
public static string GetTitle(string userFormat, string fileName)
        {
            string pattern = "^";
            char positionChar;
            string fileTitle;

            for (short i = 0; i < userFormat.Length; i++)
            {
                positionChar = userFormat[i];

                //build the regex pattern
                if (positionChar == 't')
                {
                    pattern += @"\w+";
                }
                else if (positionChar == '#')
                {
                    pattern += @"\d+";
                }
                else if (positionChar == ' ')
                {
                    pattern += @"\s+";
                }
                else
                    pattern += positionChar;
            }

            //pulls out the title with or without the delimiter
            Match title = Regex.Match(fileName, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            fileTitle = title.Groups[0].Value;

            //remove the delimiter
            string[] tempString = fileTitle.Split(@"\/.-<>".ToCharArray());
            fileTitle = "";
            foreach (string part in tempString)
            {
                fileTitle += part + " ";
            }

            return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(fileTitle);
        }
```

but im kind of stumped on how to do the extraction of the episode and season numbers. In my head im thinking the process would look something like:

- Look through the userFormat string to find the uppercase S
- Determine how many lowercase 's' are following the uppercase S
- Build the regex expression that describes this
- Search through the file name and find that pattern
- Extract the number from that pattern

Sounds simple enough but im having a hard time putting it into actions. The complication being the the fact that the format in the filename could be S01E05 or it could be simply 0105. Either scenario would be identified by the user when they define the format.

**Ex 1. the file name is battlestar.galactica.S01E05**

the user format submitted will be t.t.?ss?ee

**Ex 2. the file name is battlestar.galactica.0105**

the user format submitted will be t.t.SssEee

**Ex 3. the file name is battlestar.galactica.0501**

the user format submitted will be t.t.EeeSss

Sorry for the book... the concept is simple, the regex function should be dynamic, allowing the user to define the format of a file name to where my method can generate the expression and use it to extract information from the file name. Something is telling me that this is simpler than it seems... but im at a loss. lol... any suggestions?

Comment: Isnt the ssee format ambiguous? 0501 could be Episode 5 Season 1 or Season 5 Episode 1...(also not sure exactly what this is for but it sounds less than legal.)

Comment: If both '0501' and '0105' points to "season 1 episode 5", then I'm glad I'm not you. Or are you talking about some fictional TV series that will ever only have at most 4 seasons so if you see a 5, it has to be the episode?

Comment: As I read your question, the challenge is to start with:
 
1. 0105
2. S01E05 **OR**
3. E05S01

and end up with:

_S01E05_ (if your input is 0105 you _assume_ SxxEyy)

title and file format are irrelevant, they just get tacked on to the ends.
Is this correct?

Comment: I agree with the first comment. The format is way too ambiguous for you to be able to differentiate between what could be a season number and what could be an episode number. My suggestion is that you stick with two (maybe three) formats: SxxExx, ExxSxx, and SSEE (and not the reverse). That'll make implementation much, much simpler.

Comment: @Chad i dont think mass renaming of files is illegal. And it is only ambiguous without the user telling the tool what the format is. Using 0105 as an example: If the user specifies "ssee" then it would be read as S01E05, if they specify "eess" then it would be read as S05E01

Comment: @Cos Callis, yes that is correct. Or even 1x05 is common format as well.

Answer (score 1):

So if I read this right, you know where the the Season/Episode number is in the string because the user has told you. That is, you have `t.t.<number>.more.stuff`. And `<number>` can take one of these forms:

```
SssEee
EeeSss
ssee
eess
```

Or did you say that the user can define how many digits will be used for season and episode? That is, could it be S01E123?

I'm not sure you need a regex for this. Since you know the format, and it appears that things are separated by periods (I assume that there can't be periods in the individual fields), you should be able to use `String.Split` to extract the pieces, and you know from the user's format where the Season/Episode is in the resulting array. So you now have a string that takes one of the forms above.

You have the user's format definition and the Season/Episode number. You should be able to write a loop that steps through the two strings together and extracts the necessary information, or issues an error.

```
string UserFormat = "SssEee";
string EpisodeNumber = "0105";

int ifmt = 0;
int iepi = 0;
int season = 0;
int episode = 0;

while (ifmt <= UserFormat.Length && iepi < EpisodeNumber.Length)
{
    if ((UserFormat[ifmt] == "S" || UserFormat[ifmt] == "E"))
    {
        if (EpisodeNumber[iepi] == UserFormat[ifmt])
        {
            ++iepi;
        }
        else if (!char.IsDigit(EpisodeNumber[iepi]))
        {
            // Error! Chars didn't match, and it wasn't a digit.
            break;
        }
        ++ifmt;
    }
    else
    {
        char c = EpisodeNumber[iepi];
        if (!char.IsDigit(c))
        {
            // error. Expected digit.
        }
        if (UserFormat[ifmt] == 'e')
        {
            episode = (episode * 10) + (int)c - (int)'0';
        }
        else if (UserFormat[ifmt] == 's')
        {
            season = (season * 10) + (int)c - (int)'0';
        }
        else
        {
            // user format is broken
            break;
        }
        ++iepi;
        ++ifmt;
    }
}
```

Note that you'll probably have to do some checking to see that the lengths are correct. That is, the code above will accept S01E1 when the user's format is SssEee. There's a bit more error handling that you can add, depending on how worried you are about bad input. But I think this gives you the gist of the idea.

I have to think that's going to be a whole lot easier than trying to dynamically build regular expressions.

Comment: I think the only issue is that I do want it to be dynamic because sometimes the format might be something like battlestar.galactica-season1E5 where the delimiter changes or some other ridiculous format. The idea with the tool that im trying to build is that i would be able to tell the program how it is formatted and have it do the rest. Maybe i need to rethink my placeholders.

Comment: "Or did you say that the user can define how many digits will be used for season and episode? That is, could it be S01E123?" -yes, this is true

Answer (score 0):

After @Sinaesthetic answered my question we can reduce his original post to:
The challenge is to receive any of these inputs:

1. 0105 (if your input is 0105 you *assume* SxxEyy)
2. S01E05
3. E05S01 **OR**
4. 1x05 (read as season 1 episode 5)

and transform any of these inputs into: *S01E05*
At this point title and file format are irrelevant, they just get tacked on to the ends.

Based on that the following code will always result in 'Battlestar.Galactica.S01E05.mkv'

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     string[] inputs = new string[6] { "E05S01", "S01E05", "0105", "105", "1x05", "1x5" };
     foreach (string input in inputs)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(FormatEpisodeTitle("Battlestar.Galactica", input, "mkv"));
     }


     Console.ReadLine();
  }


  private static string FormatEpisodeTitle(string showTitle, string identifier, string fileFormat)
  {
     //first make identifier upper case
     identifier = identifier.ToUpper();

     //normalize for SssEee & EeeSee
     if (identifier.IndexOf('S') > identifier.IndexOf('E'))
     {
        identifier = identifier.Substring(identifier.IndexOf('S')) + identifier.Substring(identifier.IndexOf('E'), identifier.IndexOf('S'));
     }

     //now get rid of S and replace E with x as needed:
     identifier = identifier.Replace("S", string.Empty).Replace("E", "X");


     //at this point, if there isn't an "X" we need one, as in 105 or 0105
     if (identifier.IndexOf('X') == -1)
     {
        identifier = identifier.Substring(0, identifier.Length - 2) + "X" + identifier.Substring(identifier.Length - 2);
     }

     //now split by the 'X'
     string[] identifiers = identifier.Split('X');

     // and put it back together:
     identifier = 'S' + identifiers[0].PadLeft(2, '0') + 'E' + identifiers[1].PadLeft(2, '0');

     //tack it all together 
     return showTitle + '.' + identifier + '.' + fileFormat;

  }
```